# Form Designer unable to find type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0

In a windows form I am populating a combo box with the following code.

```
this.JackStudTypeComboBox.Items.AddRange(ViewController.GetJackStudMaterialType().ToArray());
```

When I attempt to open the Form Designer I get the message that the ViewController type is not found.

The ViewController class is located in the same project as the form.  Compiling the project has no issues, and running the project results in the expected behaviour.

So, how do I convince the Form Designer to locate this particular class, or to ignore the fact that it is unable to find it or do anything useful with it when in static design mode?

Comment: Read the comment on top of the file.

Comment: Which one, the one about modifying the code with an editor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that.

You should never put any custom logic in `InitializeComponent()`.

Move that to the constructor and everything will work fine.